# Using various state transition percentages for SMS messages in SMPPSim stub tool

Tags: testing, selenium, sms, messaging, stub

We are testing sending and receiving SMS messages with the SMPPSim stub tool of [Selenium (open source)](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html).

Mostly, it works fine for our tests.
However, in case we want to test with various state transition percentages,
we do not see any effect in the delivery notification messages we receive.
I.e. all messages received have the same status, regardless the percentages set in 
the SMPPSim configuration: All have the state DELIVERED.

In the configuration file, smppsim.props, we have the following states set:

```
# Percentage of messages that change state each time we check (excluding expiry or messages being completely discarded due to age)
# Requires an integer between 0 and 100

PERCENTAGE_THAT_TRANSITION=75

# State transition percentages. These parameters define the percentage of messages that
# transition from ENROUTE to the specified final state. The list of percentages should
# add up to 100 and must be integer values. SMPPSim will adjust the percentages if they do not.

# Percentage of messages that will transition from ENROUTE to DELIVERED
PERCENTAGE_DELIVERED=75

# Percentage of messages that will transition from ENROUTE to UNDELIVERABLE
PERCENTAGE_UNDELIVERABLE=10

# Percentage of messages that will transition from ENROUTE to ACCEPTED
PERCENTAGE_ACCEPTED=5

# Percentage of messages that will transition from ENROUTE to REJECTED
PERCENTAGE_REJECTED=10
```

Has anyone seen the same effect with the SMPPSim tool?
Is there another option in smppsim.props that can trigger different statuses, or is this simply a bug?

Comment: You should also consider posting to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am just guessing: http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/ have nothing in common with http://www.seleniumhq.org/ ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this after all? I have the same issue even if I put 100% to PERCENTAGE_REJECTED